# Mapbox and OpenStreetMap data refresh - how long until Mapbox shows the changes made in OpenStreetMap OSM?

Tags: mapbox, integration, openstreetmap, updates, frequency

How does long it take Mapbox to show OpenStreetMap changes?

- Is there a way to expedite it?
- Is there a weekly or monthly cycle?
- Does it depend on anyone accepting the changes?

I've found older answers below, but is there anything more current on the Mapbox/OSM update frequency? EXAMPLE: a major zoo wants to change and update their exhibit names, POI labels, pathways, and also use more descriptive tags for some elements (e.g. to style non-public buildings differently in Mapbox using OSM's "buiding=service" tag instead of "building=yes"). These changes by the zoo will help everyone have an updated zoo campus data set!

https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/178/how-often-does-the-main-mapnik-map-get-updated
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/257401/mapbox-not-updating-from-osm/257411#257411
https://twitter.com/Anonymaps/status/913812009547902978
https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/102/i-have-made-edits-but-they-dont-show-up-on-the-map

Answer (score 2):

The time it takes for OSM changes to populate in the Mapbox basemap depends on several factors. Typically you can expect to see changes within a couple of weeks, though the process can take a bit longer due to the fact that we have a data team dedicated to quality assurance as outlined in our documentation [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/mapbox-data/#quality-assurance).

As discussed in more detail in [our map data](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/mapbox-data/) documentation, our map data does not come exclusively from OpenStreetMap. In general, if it has been more than a several weeks since you made a significant set of changes to OpenStreetMap which have not been propagated to the Mapbox basemap, you can reach out to us with the relevant [changeset](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Changeset) ID so that we can look into applying these updates. Unless the requested changes relate to urgent matters (such as correcting map vandalism), direct requests to bypass changes any early than this will typically be asked to wait a bit longer to maintain the integrity of our data validation pipeline.

In short, there is no one "definitive" timeline for application of OSM changes, but you can always [contact us](https://www.mapbox.com/contact/) with any questions if needed.